# 404 error on a simple spring mvc aplication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

[Project Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eirp.jpg)I have gone through most of the question on this site related to **404 resource not found error** on Sring mvc application. I tried all solutions and still ended up with no resolution for over two days. I am new to spring MVC and tried out a sample application from the link 
[Simple Spring MVC app](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-form-handling-example.html#.VkbK9PkrLIU)

My code is exactly as mentioned on the site above. But no matter what change I make, still get a 404 error.

Here's my **web.xml** section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>abc</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>  
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  
        </servlet-class>  
      <init-param>  
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value></init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The controller file, 
**EmployeeController.java**

```
@Controller  
public class EmployeeController {  

  @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
  public ModelAndView employee() {  
    return new ModelAndView("employeeForm", "command", new Employee());  
   }  

  @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
  public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Employee employee, ModelMap model) {  
     model.addAttribute("name", employee.getName());  
     model.addAttribute("age", employee.getAge());  
     model.addAttribute("empId", employee.getEmpId());  
     model.addAttribute("salary", employee.getSalary());  
     return "employeeDetail";  
   }  
}
```

where Employee is my POJO class with setter and getter methods.

Here is my **employeeForm.jsp**

```
<form:form action="/addEmployee" method="POST">        
<table><tbody>  
<tr>        <td><form:label path="empId">Employee :</form:label></td>      <td><form:input path="empId"></form:input></td>    </tr>  
<tr>      <td><form:label path="name">EmployeeName:/form:label></form:label></td>       <td><form:input path="name"></form:input></td>    </tr>  
<tr>       <td><form:label path="age">Employee Age:</form:label></td>       <td><form:input path="age"></form:input></td>     </tr>  
<tr>      <td><form:label path="salary">Employee Salary:</form:label></td>     <td><form:input path="salary"></form:input></td>    </tr>  
<tr>         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>  </td>       </tr>  
</tbody></table>  
</form:form>
```

here is my **sdnext-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava.emp.controller">  
</context:component-scan>  
  <context:annotation-config/>
   <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="viewResolver">  
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>  
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
```

Comment: According to your configuration I want give you the hint, that the url you must request to invoke your controller is at least `http://localhost:8080/<APPLICATIONNAME>/sdnext/employee`. (you did not post the complete controller) - but what I want to say, it is likely that, if your application name is `sdnext` too, then you will have two `sdnext` in your url! --- second: when ever you have a 404 problem, please post at least the url you try to request!

Comment: Please check the answer that I posted. Accept it if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @Ralph i have edited my post accordingly to include the complete controller.. Also the URL's im trying to access is
**URL:**
that am trying to access

**http://localhost:8080/sdnext/employee**

where sdnext is my servlet name from web.xml

also i have tried accessing using

**http://localhost:8080/abc/sdnext/employee**

where abc is my application name

i still get a 404 error

Comment: Please access the application using this URL localhost:8080/abc/employee

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a fundamental mistake. Say your project name is bunbub-proj, so the url to access is `localhost:8080/bunbub-proj`. When you POST to `/addEmployee`, you are actually hitting `localhost:8080/addEmployee` instead of `localhost:8080/bunbub-proj/addEmployee`

The fix is to simply append a `.` to all of your `links/urls`. E.g. `<form:form action="./addEmployee" method="POST">`

> Note: Browser considers localhost:8080 as the base url or the host
>   url.

Comment: **URL:**
that am trying to access

**http://localhost:8080/sdnext/employee**

where sdnext is my servlet name from web.xml

also i have tried accessing using

**http://localhost:8080/abc/sdnext/employee**

where abc is my application name

i still get a 404 error

Comment: i have also tried to append a .  as you suggested, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Please paste in complete the web.xml in your question. Will fix it now.

Comment: i get this error in my console 
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/abc/sdnext/employee] in DispatcherServlet with name 'sdnext'

Comment: The project name is abc, if not let me know in the comment. URL to access localhost:8080/abc/employee

Then do the changes I suggested in the answer.

Comment: i still get a 404 error .. let me know if this is right in employeeform.jsp
<form:form action="./sdnext/addEmployee" method="POST">  
since my servletname is sdnext

Comment: Why the hack you using **sdnext**  in url. You don't have to use it in url. This url has to work `localhost:8080/abc/employee`.

Comment: Please paste me the project file structure. From the IDE file explorer. The point is to keep the display name in `<display-name>abc</display-name>` in `web.xml`  and the proj name same.

Comment: Im not using sdnext in the url, i have tried the url you have given and it still doesnt work

Comment: im exactly following the tutorial from this link, as is http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-form-handling-example.html#.VkbK9PkrLIU

Comment: i have also tried  <form:form action="./addEmployee" method="POST"> in the employeeForm.jsp , doesnt work

Comment: i have updated the project folder structure above in the post